# Whats a better way to group dates on a form

Tags: forms, layout, dates

Looking to improve a claims form that claims assessors to review and approve in the insurance industry. One of the comments the user mentioned was that dates related to the claim was all over the place. based on this i'm looking to group the dates in the form together.

Is there a better way to group the date information. something similar to a timeline component, however in this case the dates arent progressively related.

**Current layout**(with all dates highlighted)
[image]

**Revised**
[image]

Comment: What happens when you click view internal remarks? Is there save button on this interface somewhere? Claim type field is just input, meaning no autocomplete? When does claim complete date becomes provided?

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a timeline like this but in horizontal direction?
Here are a few examples from Flowbite design system: https://flowbite.com/docs/components/timeline/

[image]